# "invalid download uri" from Play Store on a Huawei phone

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, huawei

I have a g350-u00 device that was shipped with JB 4.1.2 but without Gapps. To add Google account, I rooted the device and copied .apk files to /system/apk from gapps package http://goo.im/gapps/gapps-jb-20121011-signed.zip. After a couple of hard resets I have a working system with Gmail and Play Store. The latter fails to install any app with toast "invalid download uri". How can I cure the system?

Answer (score -1):

Try "all apps in play store" xposed mod

Comment: Just to clarify, xposed mod has an `all apps in play store` feature?

Comment: Yes it does :p try it